# Does the use of the words "persistant" and "go for" , suit the text below?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

As I spotted the lesion under my tongue, I went for (I started using I mean) Chlorhexidine mouthwash. As you know, Doctor, it should be gargled twice a day, But I just gargled it one time, yesterday and forgot to continue. Is it possible the bactria in my lesion becomes persistant to the antibiotic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Went for” is fine.

Instead of “persistent”, you mean “[resistant](http://www.who.int/mediacentre/factsheets/fs194/en/)”.